# for文を抜けるだけのbreak文の使い方は合っていますか?

Tags: python

途中で`break`文を2つ使っており、1つ目のbreak文は問題がないと思うのですが、2つ目のbreak文はfor文を抜けるだけのために使っています。

賢いfor文の抜け方はないでしょうか?

> **問題**
>
> Nが1以上9以下の2つの整数の積で表すことができるか判定を判定せよ。

```py
N = 15;
canDevide = False;

for i in range(10):
  for m in range(10):
    result = i * m

    if (N == result):
      canDevide = True
      print(str(i) + " " + str(m))
      break

  if (canDevide):
    break

print(canDevide)
```

Comment: metropolis様のrange(1, 10)がいいと思います。class range(start, stop[, step])。https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range

Comment: range(1, 9+1)、range(1, 1+9)こんな書き方しないのかなあ?

Comment: 確かに0は意味が無かったですね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nが1以上9以下の2つの整数の積で表すことができるか判定せよ。

以下は「賢いfor文の抜け方」ではなく、二重の for loop を一つにしています。
※ Walrus operator を使用していますので Python 3.8 以降で動作します

```py
N = 15
canDivide = False
for i in range(1, 10):
  if N%i == 0 and 0 < (m := N//i) < 10:
    print(f'{i} {m}')
    canDivide = True
    break

print(canDivide)
```

Comment: Walrus operator を知らなったですが、代入と出力が同時にできるのですね。

Answer (score 0):

> 賢いfor文の抜け方はないでしょうか?

break にフラグを使用したくないという意図であれば for else を使用して

```
  #if (canDevide):
  #  break
  else: continue
  break
```

とする方法はあります。
が、わかりやすいかは微妙ですね。

Answer (score 0):

元のままのフラグと `break` でも十分だと思いますが、意味的に無理がなければ関数にして`return`するという手もあります。

```
def canDevide(N):
    for i in range(10):
        for m in range(10):
            result = i * m

            if (N == result):
                canDevide = True
                print(str(i) + " " + str(m))
                return True

    return False

print(canDevide(15))
```

Comment: 関数にしてしまえば、早めにreturnが出来て、いいですね。